# Generic vector of templates

Tags: c++, templates

For me generic vectors of templates are vector that can take template with any argument list. Like this

```
vector<Foo<?>> foos;
foos.push_back(Foo<int>(5));
foos.push_back(Foo<Bar>(Bar()));
foos.push_back(Foo<string>("bar"));
```

EDIT:

This is why I need this

```
#ifndef EVENT_DISPATCHER_H
#define EVENT_DISPATCHER_H
// #include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

namespace Whitedrop {
    template <typename... T> class EventDispatcher {
    public:

        EventDispatcher(std::string eventID)
        {

        }

        void on(std::function<void(T...)> callback)
        {
            mCallbacks.push_back(callback);
        }

        void trigger(T&... args)
        {
            for (auto f : mCallbacks)
                f(args...);
        }

    protected:
        std::vector<std::function<void(T...)>> mCallbacks;

    };
    std::map<std::string, EventDispatcher<?> > dispatchers; // HERE <--------

    template<typename... T> void registerListener(std::string eventID, std::function<void(T...)> callback)
    {
        if (!dispatchers.count(eventID))
        {

            dispatchers[eventID] = new EventDispatcher<T...>(eventID);

            return;
        }
        dispatchers.find(eventID)->second.on(callback);
        //std::shared_ptr<Chunk> chunk = mChunks.find(pos)->second;

    }

    template<typename... T> void invokeListener(std::string eventID, T... args)
    {
        if (!dispatchers.count(eventID))
        {

            return;
        }
        dispatchers.find(eventID)->second->trigger(args...);
    }
};
#endif
```

SInce it seems not possible, how can I resolve my issue?

Comment: You might be looking for type erasure. You could try a `std::vector< std::unique_ptr< EventDispatcherBase > >`, with all specializations of `EventDispatcher` inheriting from that base class.

Comment: @Potatoswatter what does base contains? It'll need to specify the arg list again, won't it?

Comment: It should be an abstract base with virtual functions as necessary. The base class should not be a template or know about any of the derived classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is no.

The compiler needs to figure out types and sizes.

**EDIT**

Use inheritance

Eg

```
class Event {
   private:
      std::string m_id;
   public:
       Event(std:string &id) : m_id(id) { }
       std:string EveentId() const { return m_id;}
       virtual void DoEvent() = 0;
};

class MyEvent : Event {
   public:
      MyEvent() : Event("MyEvent") { }
       DoEvent() { std::cout << "MyEvent" << std::endl;
};
```

Then have a list of events

i.e.

```
std::vector<std::shard_ptr<Event>> events;

events.push_back<std::make_shared<MyEvent>());

events[0]->DoEvent();
```

Comment: Then I loose my template, no? Oh wait I just understood. event pattern,  but with classes rather than templates. But I need to figure out which are the multple events before and then add a function matching in base or another class?

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible. Class templates are templates, not types. The `std::vector` template requires a *type* as its first argument, not a template.

You can use class templates to produce types, but you have to choose one particular type for each instantiation of the `std::vector` template.

---

More generally, the nature of a template parameter tells you what kind of argument you can use. In C++ there are three "ontological tiers": values ("things that *have* types), types ("things that *are* types), and templates ("things that make any of the three"). Each can appear as a template parameter:

```
template < int A                        // Value (int prvalue)
         , typename B,                  // Type
         , template <typename> class C  // Template
         > struct Foo {};

Foo<10, double, std::allocator> foo;
//   A     B            C
```

Comment: Thank you. So how to bypass that (see edit) in my case?

Comment: @Vinz243: I wouldn't call that a "limit". It's a rather profound and fundamental aspect of C++'s type and object model (see edit). But a) search this website for hundreds of duplicates, and b) think about how you could possibly *use* such a hypothetical object.

Comment: OK, I understand it's bad. How should I improve my code to avoid such cases?

Comment: @Vinz243; You cannot *improve* it. You need to totally rethink what's going on. Start by answering my question (b) above: How would you *use* a hypothetical generic vector? You should immediately see that that doesn't make sense. How would you know which callback is suitable for which arguments?

Comment: Because of the string was specified. It's an event id, and each event have its own parameters, no?

Comment: So using inheritance is better?

Answer (score 1):

std::vector is a homogeneous container, which means it can only contain one type. Note that Foo<> is a family of types not a single type, the type of std::vector is different depending on the template parameter.

Now, you can achieve what you want using two methods I can think off, the first is by erasing the type, for example you can use `std::vector<boost::any>`, but note that it completely erases the type (the type info is lost), and is not a compile time operation.

The second way is using a [tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), this is a compile time fixed-size container, which means you *can't* add new elements at runtime, because the type of each object is determined at compile time.